# Python: Writing only the last line of the string when trying to write the string to a new file

Tags: python, string, writefile

I am reading a text file as a list and extracting only the first column of data with " " (keyboard space) as a split separator.

I am trying to write the resultant string data into a new file.

While I create and write the string data into the new file, only the last line of the string data is present in the newly created file.

For example, when I print the string data, I am able to see the entire string.

```
graphics/1.jpg
graphics/2.jpg
graphics/3.jpg
graphics/4.jpg
graphics/5.jpg
```

However, the new file is created but contains only the last line:

```
graphics/5.jpg
```

I tried using "a" instead of "w" for writing the new file as specified in a different stack overflow thread.

Not sure what is that I need to do to write the entire string data into the newly created file. Please help!

```
with open(fig_file, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            fields = line.split(" ")
            field1 = fields[0]
            print(field1)

with open("list.txt","w") as wp:
        wp.write(field1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only writing one line to the file, ever!

This should work.

```
lines = []
with open(fig_file, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            fields = line.split(" ")
            field1 = fields[0]
            print(field1)

            lines.append(field1)


with open("list.txt","w") as wp:
        wp.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: comment the reason for the downvote so that i can correct the answer. cheers.

Comment: Not a wrong solution at all but the reason might be that I wouldn't store every field in a list when not necessary.

Comment: Both solutions yield the same result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is only writing the last `field1` value to the output file. If you want to write all fields, you need to write them during the loop like this:

```
with open(fig_file, "r") as f:
    with open("list.txt","w") as wp:
        for line in f:
            fields = line.split(" ")
            field1 = fields[0]
            wp.write(field1)
```

Comment: Both solutions yield the same result. Thanks!